# PHP MySQLi prepared statements don't appear to bind or pass variables - but works with PDO prepare

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, prepared-statement, mariadb

I'm having some trouble with an application that's recently stopped working and I can't figure out what the issue might be.

Reading from the database is working well, but when I try to insert, or update an existing record it doesn't work. Occasionally the record field value is set to null instead of the variable value.

This application is currently running on a shared host and it was working fine for several months until just a week ago. I have the UAT instance sitting on another host with another provider and it seems to be working without issue.

During my investigation, I noticed that if I updated or inserted via the standard PHP MYSQLi procedural statement that the record was being correctly updated/inserted, but when I try and bind it via the prepared statement that it doesn't work.

No errors are being thrown by PHP/MySQL.

I've tried simplifying things by creating a simple test script that updates one record with a value.

**This works:**

```
<?php
    // Connection file
    require 'connection.php';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // set parameters and execute
    $firstname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["firstname"]);

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET first_name='$firstname' WHERE uid=1";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Updated record successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

**While this does not:**

```
<?php
    // Connection file
    require 'connection.php';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // set parameters and execute
    $firstname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["firstname"]);

    // prepare and bind
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET first_name=? WHERE uid =1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $firstname);


    $stmt->execute();

    echo "Updated record successfully";

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

I'm running PHP v7.0.30, Apache v2.4.33 and MySQL v10.2.15 (MariaDB)

Any ideas. This is driving me crazy...

I've just tried returning the number of affected rows for the second example.

```
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $stmt ->affected_rows);
```

If the first_name in the database table has a value, and I run the script outputting the number of rows, it returns *'Affected rows 1'*. When I check the database I can see that the value is now empty.

What could cause this? Some sort of encoding issue perhaps?

**UPDATE 1**

Just added var_dump($stmt, $firstname); to second example after bind.

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(0) } string(3) "Bob"
```

Affected rows: 1

and

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(0) } string(4) "Jack"
```

Affected rows: 0`

**UPDATE 2**

I'm starting to think this is a server issue.
I've just tested updating a record using PDO prepare and it's working.

```
<?php
    // Connection file
    require 'connection.php';

    // set parameters
    $firstname = $_GET["firstname"];
    $id = 1;

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // prepare sql and bind parameters
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET first_name=? WHERE uid=?");
        $stmt->execute([$firstname,$id]);

        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    $conn = null;

?>
```

When I try and execute a prepared statement to SELECT, I get a '503 Service Unavailable'. Works fine locally.

```
<?php
    // Connection file
    require 'connection.php';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // set parameters and execute
    $id = 1;

    //create a prepared statement
    $query = "SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE uid=?";
    $stmt  = $conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt ->bind_param('i', $id);

    //execute query
    $stmt ->execute();

    //bind result variables
    $stmt ->bind_result($first_name);

    //fetch records
    while($stmt ->fetch()) {
        print $first_name;
    }   

    //close connection
    $stmt ->close();

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**FINAL UPDATE - ISSUE RESOLVED**

My hosting provider was able to resolve the issue. It seems that the nd_mysqli PHP extension was disabled. With it enabled the above examples work and my application is now functional.

Comment: FWIW, HTML has nothing to do with SQL. You should not HTML-escape values for an SQL query. In the first code this leads to the query still being open to SQL injection. The second query is safe, but now you have the problem of having HTML-encoded data in your database for no good reason…

Comment: Noted. These are just simple examples I copied from online tutorials. I'm not escaping this way in my application.

Comment: @Mkov Please edit your question to include the real code you have in your application. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The code above is what I'm using to debug the error. This is currently in the same environment as my application.

Comment: @Mkov What is the output of `var_dump($stmt, $firstname);` after the `bind_param()` call? What is the output you get in case there were one affected row and in case there were no affected rows?

Comment: Just added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINAL UPDATE - ISSUE RESOLVED

My hosting provider was able to resolve the issue. It seems that the nd_mysqli PHP extension was disabled. With it enabled the above examples work and my application is now functional.